# One of conjectures of De Giorgi

Tags: sobolev-spaces

**conjecture:** If $\exp(tw), \exp(tw^{-1}) \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}$ for each $t > 0$ then $w$ is regular weight.

$w$ is regular if weighted Sobolev space $W^l_p(\Omega,w)$ is equal to the completion of $C^{\infty}$ with respect to the weighted norm $\|\cdot \mid W^l_p(\Omega,w)\|$.

Question: Is there some progress with this conjecture?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this conjecture?

Comment: I've read about it here http://www.spm.uem.br/bspm/pdf/vol26/Art11.pdf